# How to get google account profile picture in android app

Tags: java, android

I am using firebase google sign in in my project. I want to display the account name, email and profile picture. I can display the name and email without any problem but I am not able to display the users google account profile picture. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

according to [Docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/people#retrieve_profile_information_for_a_signed-in_user)

```
GoogleSignInAccount acct = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getActivity());
if (acct != null) {
  String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
  String personEmail = acct.getEmail();
  Uri personPhoto = acct.getPhotoUrl(); // this line to get  profile picture 
}
```

then you can use Picasso Library to show images in ImageView

```
Picasso.with(this).load(personPhoto).into(R.id.imageview);
```

Comment: thanks bro i'll try it